# Django Pass URL Parameter To Decorator

Tags: python, django, redirect, model-view-controller, decorator

trying to redirect user to a page if they're not staff members. how do i pass a url parameter to a django decorator?

```
# categories.urls.py

from django.urls import path
from categories.views import CategoryInfoView, CategoryDetailView

app_name = 'categories'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:handle>', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name = 'category'),
    path('<slug:handle>/info/', CategoryInfoView.as_view(), name = 'category_info'),
]

# categories.view.py

class CategoryInfoView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'categories/info.html'
    context_object_name = 'category'

    @redirect_if_not_staff(redirect_to = reverse_lazy('categories:category')) # <-- how do i pass the url parameter here?!
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Category, handle = self.kwargs.get('handle'))

# decorator.py

def redirect_if_not_staff(*setting_args, **setting_kwargs):
    """
    A decorator to redirect users if they are not staff
    Can be used as: @decorator(with, arguments, and = kwargs) or @decorator
    """

    no_args = False
    redirect_to = setting_kwargs.get('redirect_to', reverse_lazy('index'))

    if len(setting_args) == 1 and not setting_kwargs and callable(setting_args[0]):
        func = setting_args[0]
        no_args = True

    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def redirect_function(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.is_staff:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
            
            return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

        return redirect_function

    if no_args:
        return decorator(func)
    else:
        return decorator
```

how do i get **localhost:8000/categories/sample/info/** to redirect to **localhost:8000/categories/sample/** if the user is not a staff using decorators

currently getting this error
`NoReverseMatch at /categories/agriculture/info/`

`Reverse for 'category' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['categories/(?P<handle>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\Z']`

Answer (score 0):

Not a django expert, however I think the redirection issue you are facing has nathing to do with decorators but with the django redirection by itself.

In your case I would substitute "redirect_to" for a function like `get_url` in `def decorator` to determine the url:

```
 def get_url(self):
        dict = {'handle': 'sample'}
        url = reverse('game', kwargs=dict)
        return url
```

And in  `def redirect_function`:

```
def redirect_function(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.is_staff:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_url())
            
            return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

        return redirect_function

    if no_args:
        return decorator(func)
    else:
        return decorator
```

Thats the structure I use for any kind of redirection and for the moment I have faced no issues for the moment.
I hope it helps